# for loop reading files line by line

Tags: bash, shell

I feel like i have used 'for loop' several times to read a file line by line and do an action with the output. But now whatever i do, I can't get it to work. I can get it to work using the 'while read' loop. But I am just curious why my for loop is not working anymore. I am pretty sure I am doing some simple mistake. But I can't seem to figure out what it is. Here is one variation of the command I am trying out. I tried several variations with changing the quotes or sometime using and cat and other times not. But every time i am getting the same result.

```
$ for x in "cat test.sh" ; do echo $x ; done
cat test.sh
$
```

Comment: What is the output you expect and what are you currently getting?

Comment: FYI, `echo "$x"`, not `echo $x`, if you want to avoid string-splitting and glob-expansion. Even better would be `printf '%s\n' "$x"`, as that will print sequences such as `-E` or `-n` which some versions of echo will silently parse as options rather than treating as literal arguments.

Answer (score 4):

The basic way to do what you expect is :

```
while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < test.sh
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

### NOTE

If you use a `for` loop, you are facing problems with *shell word splitting* on spaces on each lines

Comment: Not mean to offend you. I have the feeling, when someone answers a simple question, get more votes easily.

Answer (score 2):

you can use,

```
while read line
do

task 

done < file
```

or

```
for line in 'cat dbs.txt'; 
do

task

done
```

Comment: The for-line-in-cat approach is wrong -- it iterates over glob-expanded words, not lines. The `while read line` approach is also somewhat wrong -- without using more arguments to read and controlling IFS, it's trimming trailing whitespace and processing backslash-escapes rather than feeding data literally.